# Subdomain not correctly redirecting from http to https

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301, subdomain

I got a little subdomain redirect problem. This is my config:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name sub4.example.com sub3.example.com sub2.example.com sub1.example.com www.example.com;

  access_log           /var/log/nginx/www.example.com_access.log;
  error_log            /var/log/nginx/www.example.com_error.log;

  location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy default_server;
  server_name sub4.example.com sub3.example.com sub2.example.com sub1.example.com www.example.com;
  root /srv/www/www.example.com/current/public;

  ssl_certificate ssl-certificates/wildcard.example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key ssl-certificates/wildcard.example.com.key;

  access_log           /var/log/nginx/www.example.com_access.log;
  error_log            /var/log/nginx/www.example.com_error.log;
  ...
}
```

All `https` domains work as expected but all `http` requests redirect to `https://sub4.example.com`.

Anyone knows why this could be happening?

Comment: don't use `$server_name`. Use `$host` or `$http_host`

Comment: I searched and googled for `$host` and `$http_host` but I'm not quite sure how to use it. Can you give me an example? Also, another solution would be to create server blocks for each subdomain, is that correct?

Comment: Oh, man… Put `$host` instead of `$server_name` in redirection directive.